# Outputting x to y

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source

### Challenge

You must choose one number `x` (`y = x + 9`) and create ten unique programs which each print out one of the numbers in the range `x` to `y` inclusive. However, there are three twists:

- Each program's score is the difference between length of your program in bytes and `n` (where `n` is the number that the program outputs). i.e. If a program is 12 bytes long and it outputs the number 15, its score is 3 (`|15-12| = 3`).

  - You must not use comments to achieve this byte count.
- Your program must not contain any number which is contained within the number which the program outputs. i.e. If a program outputs `1659`, the program cannot contain 1, 6, 5 or 9
- Your program must not contain any of the characters which are the first letters of the number which the program outpts. i.e. If the program outputs `1659`, the program cannot contain o, s, f or n (**o**ne, **s**ix, **f**ive and **n**ine)

### Rules

If any number is impossible, this is counted as a DNP. You should declare all DNPs in your range.

The following is a list of numbers and their spellings. The disallowed characters for each are highlighted in bold:

- 0: **Z**ero
- 1: **O**ne
- 2: **T**wo
- 3: **T**hree
- 4: **F**our
- 5: **F**ive
- 6: **S**ix
- 7: **S**even
- 8: **E**ight
- 9: **N**ine

### Scoring

Your overall score is the sum of all your programs' scores.

### Winning

The person with the lowest score with the fewest DNPs wins.

In the event of a tie, the person whose last edit was earliest wins.

Comment: Do I understand right that I can choose `n=1000000` (one million), write programs that output 1000000 to 1000009 without the banned letters or digits, and then pad them to the required length using anything other than comments?

Comment: @xnor Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: Can we output numbers in base 1, i.e. unary?

Comment: @nimi Yes, but only if it's your language's native format. So, Retina can output in unary, but Python cannot

Comment: Tie-breaking by lowest **x** would have been a better idea, but Jelly still manages **x = 0** without effort.

Comment: @Dennis I disagree with lowest **x** as that would make it impossible for non-golfing languages to compete (which actually could be competitive here due to the scoring mechanism). Unfortunately we haven't seen any such answers yet, but I feel like they have the potential of being really interesting. Tie-break by first wasn't the best idea either and I'm not sure what would have been a good tie-breaker.

Comment: @Dennis I agree with Emigna on that. I have my Python x=40 answer tie with the Jelly x=3/x=2/x=0 answer, and probably most of the answers here. But I would suggest another rule; in the event of a tie, the answer with the latest edit *by the OP* will win. I might post that on meta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/), score = 0

Chosen **x = 1**

**Programs**

**1**: Variable initialized as 1

```
X
```

**2**: zeroth prime number

```
0Ø
```

**3**: first digit of 2^15

```
žG¬
```

**4**: integer root of 16

```
žvtï
```

**5**: first digit of pi + 2

```
žqS¬Ì
```

**6**: first digit of 2nd to last set from the powerset of 256

```
žzœ¨¤¬
```

**7**: the (e // e)th primeth prime

```
žržr÷ØØ
```

**8**: the first 2 digits of the sum of the 10 first multiples of 3, divided by 2

```
TLx+O¨Y÷
```

**9**: ceil(sqrt(sum(range[1..10])))+2 XOR 1st prime

```
TLOtîÌXØ^
```

**10**: int(prod([1..9])/2^15)-1

```
žmS¨PžG/ï<
```

Answer (score 5):

## [brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), score = 0

Chosen **x = 15**

**15**

```
+++[>+++++<-]>.
```

**16**

```
+++[>+++++<-]>+.
```

**17**

```
>+[>-[-<]>>]>+-+.
```

**18**

```
+++[>++++++<-]>+-.
```

**19**

```
+++[>++++++<-]>++-.
```

**20**

```
++++[>+++++<-]>+-+-.
```

**21**

```
+++[>+++++++<-]>++--.
```

**22**

```
+++[>+++++++<-]>+--++.
```

**23**

```
>-[++++[<]>->+]<+++---.
```

**24**

```
+++++[>+++++<-]>++----+.
```

Output is in byte values.

Answer (score 4):

## Jelly, score 0

**x=3**, using ten completely different methods

```
2ÆN          -  3: second prime
6ḃ2S         -  4: sum of digits of 6 in bijective-base 2
2*4BL        -  5: number of bits in 16
2+1R+/       -  6: third triangle number
⁵×ØeḞDṪ      -  7: 1st decimal place of Euler's number
12,6_/+2     -  8: Number of vertices on a cube
ȷ*4×ØPḞDṪ    -  9: the 12th decimal place of pi
9999b9999Ḍ   - 10: decimal of 9999 base 9999
45683g38654  - 11: greatest common divisor of 45683 and its reverse
6RLRL×7RLÆfS - 12: sum of the prime factors of 42 (6*7 is the ultimate question)
```

Run all ten at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MsOGTgo24biDMlMKMio0QkwKMisxUisvCuKBtcOXw5hl4bieROG5qgoxMiw2Xy8rMgrItyo0w5fDmFDhuJ5E4bmqCjk5OTliOTk5OeG4jAo0NTY4M2czODY1NAo2UkxSTMOXN1JMw4ZmUwrigbXCucKj4oKs&input=&args=CgoKCg)

---

Previous (just another boring answer)

**x=2**

```
1‘          - 1 incremented            1+1 =  2
1‘‘         - 1 incremented twice    1+1+1 =  3
1‘‘‘        - 1 incremented thrice 1+1+1+1 =  4
1‘‘‘‘       -                ... 1+1+1+1+1 =  5
1‘‘‘‘‘      -              ... 1+1+1+1+1+1 =  6
1‘‘‘‘‘‘     -            ... 1+1+1+1+1+1+1 =  7
1‘‘‘‘‘‘‘    -          ... 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 =  8
1‘‘‘‘‘‘‘    -        ... 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 =  9
3‘‘‘‘‘‘‘‘’  - 3 incremented eight times then decremented 
                       3+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1 = 10
3‘‘‘‘‘‘‘‘‘’ - 3 incremented nine times then decremented
                     3+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1 = 11
```

---

If tie-break is on lowest **x** then for **x=0**

```
          - 0: empty program returns zero
¬         - 1: logical not
¬‘        - 2: logical not then increment
¬‘‘       - 3: logical not then increment twice
¬‘‘‘      - 4: logical not then increment thrice
¬‘‘‘‘     - 5: logical not then increment four times
¬‘‘‘‘‘    - 6: logical not then increment five times
¬‘‘‘‘‘‘   - 7: logical not then increment six times
¬‘‘‘‘‘‘‘  - 8: logical not then increment seven times
¬‘‘‘‘‘‘‘‘ - 9: logical not then increment eight times
```

Run all ten at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=CsKsCsKs4oCYCsKs4oCY4oCYCsKs4oCY4oCY4oCYCsKs4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCYCsKs4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCYCsKs4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCYCsKs4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCYCsKs4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCY4oCYCuKBtcK5wqPigqw&input=)

Comment: Nice ones! It was answers like these I was hoping to see more of on this challenge.

Comment: +1 for going the extra mile and making interesting answers :)

Comment: @Emigna yeah, I think the idea of "unique" probably should have been specified *somehow* as being essentially different (although I'm not quite sure how - I have used the same operators and literals in multiple programs. banning that would make for an interesting twist, although it would exclude some languages)

Comment: For x=0, you can also do Unary (using `‘` instead of `¬`).

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, score 0

x = 14

```
print +2*3+3+5
print 6+2*3+3+0
print 7+2*3+3+00
print 6+2*3+5+0+0
print-~6+2*3+5+0+0
exec"pri\x6et 22-3"
exec"prin\164 9+8+3"
exec"prin\x74 9+9+03"
exec"prin\164-~9+8+04"
exec"prin\164-~9-~8+04"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Emotinomicon](//conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html), 205 bytes

x = 16

```
71 ⏬⏬
81 ⏬ ⏬
91⏪⏬⏩
02⏬⏬ ℹ
 12⏬⏬ ℹ
22⏪⏬⏬⏩
32 ⏪⏬⏬⏩
42⏬⏬
ℹℹ➕
```

Pro tip: Prepend a  before each snippet to clean the output.

Answer (score 0):

#### Pyke, x=2, score 0

```
1h
1hh
1hhh
1hhhh
1hhhhh
1hhhhhh
1hhhhhhh
1hhhhhhhh
ZOhhhhhhhh
ZOhhhhhhhhh
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Pyth, x=2, score 0

```
h1
hh1
hhh1
hhhh1
hhhhh1
hhhhhh1
hhhhhhh1
hhhhhhhh1
hhhhhhyyld
hhhhhhhyyld
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, *x* = 4, score 0

```
3+1&
4+01&
5+001&
6+0001&
7+00001&
8+000001&
8+2+22-22&
9+00000002&
9+000000003&
9+0000000004&
```

Anonymous functions. Take no input and return numbers as output.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 7 , x=4,score=0

```
2+2;
11-6;
18-12;
3+2**2;
2+2+2+2;
3+2**2+2;
2+2+2+2+2;
3+2**2+2+2;
3*3+3+6-3-3;
4**2-5+2+0*2;
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/features.commandline.usage.php No I don't forget it. You are right the ** operator belongs to PHP 5.6 but I am was not sure if this feature is new in PHP 7.

Comment: It must be something like http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php . I use the right side on https://repl.it/languages/php . I found http://david.acz.org/phpa/ but this plugin does not exactly make it

Comment: Ah I see, you're using a *REPL*. I think you should tag your language then as something like *PHP/REPL* or *REPL/PHP*. Here's a [discussion on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7842/41859) about it.

Answer (score 0):

### [Ru](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/ru), score = 0

`x = 2`

```
’1
’’1
’’’1
’’’’1
’’’’’1
’’’’’’1
’’’’’’’1
’’’’’’’’1
→’’’’’’’’2
→’’’’’’’’’2
```

Answer (score 0):

### dc, x = 5, score 0

```dc
# Note: in dc all numbers typed in use the input radix. By default it is 10, which
#means that a number like CF is not 207, but 12*10^1 + 15*10^0 = 135.

CCDap              # 5   print character with the ASCII code  (1333 % 256 =) 53
CCEadp             # 6   print character with the ASCII code  (1334 % 256 =) 54
CCFaddp            # 7   print character with the ASCII code  (1335 % 256 =) 55
ACBAaddp           # 8   print character with the ASCII code (11320 % 256 =) 56
ACBBadddp          # 9   print character with the ASCII code (11321 % 256 =) 57
Addddddddp         #10   print 10 (A)
Bdddddddddp        #11   print 11 (B)
Cddddddddddp       #12   print 12 (C)
Ddddddddddddp      #13   print 13 (D)
Eddddddddddddp     #14   print 14 (E)
```

Comments were added for a better understanding. All the above 10 programs are standalone, but you could have a bonus program that prints all the numbers from 5 to 14, by copy-pasting each code into one single file.